# Visual Studio 2017 instrumentation profiling: Error VSP1381: Buffer pool has been exhausted

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am trying to profile a C++ program using Visual Studio 2017. I get the error below:

> Visual Studio 2017 instrumentation profiling: Error VSP1381: Buffer pool has been exhausted. Profiling data will be ignored until VSPerfMon.exe is shutdown or a new VSP file is created.

I was previously using Visual Studio 2012 and this instrumentation profiling works fine for me there. But switching to 2017 resulted in this above error.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Per Ramhound's suggest I ran the command `vsperfcmd /admin:driver,start /admin:service,start`

Below is the output.

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionToo
ls>vsperfcmd /admin:driver,start /admin:service,start
Microsoft (R) VSPerf Command Version 15.0.27906 x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

driver,start

Installing VSPerfDrv150
VSPerfDrv150 installed
Starting VSPerfDrv150
VSPerfDrv150 started

service,start

Installing VSPerfSrv
Starting VSPerfSrv
VSPerfSrv started
```

Comment: What is the output of `vsperfcmd /admin:driver,start /admin:service,start `?

Comment: @Ramhound, Below is the output Microsoft (R) VSPerf Command Version 15.0.27906 x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.



driver,start

Installing VSPerfDrv150
VSPerfDrv150 installed
Starting VSPerfDrv150
VSPerfDrv150 started

service,start

Installing VSPerfSrv
Starting VSPerfSrv
VSPerfSrv started. Thanks so much

Comment: Please edit your question and format the output so other users can read it.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry about that. I have edited the question. Thanks